# Setting permissions for OSGi bundles

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, equinox, accesscontrolexception

I've run into a problem trying to limit actions that the OSGi bundle can perform. According to the documents I've read, permissions for OSGi bundles should be set in OSGI-INF/permissions.perm file within bundle's JAR. However, no matter what I write in that file (and no matter if this file exists or not), bundles seem to have AllPermissions. More specifically, I start OSGi from command line with command

```
D:\temp\2>java -jar org.eclipse.osgi_3.3.2.R33x_v20080105.jar -console
-Djava.security.manager=org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.FrameworkSecurityManager
```

Then I install bundle with command

```
osgi> install file:/d:/temp/2/J1.jar
```

and start it. When I try to perform an operation that should be restricted (e.g., accessing a file, loading a library, etc.), operation always succeeds, even with empty permissions.perm file. How do I make permissions specified in permissions.perm file active?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The permissions.perm does not specify what the bundle may do. It specifies what the bundle wants to do: See http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/11/permissions-in-osgi.html

So this file seems to be there to be able to fail fast if permissions are missing. You can even leave it out if this is not necessary for you.

The real security settings have to be done on the framework. See this for felix: https://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-framework-security.html

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get the thing working - checked in my code if the SecurityManager was available or not. It seemed that on old version of OSGi JAR I've used security manager was not working. I've tried org.eclipse.osgi_3.7.2.v20120110-1415.jar instead, and permissions set for bundle in OSGI-INF/permissions.perm file work fine.